# Is it a good idea to put url shortner code in node module?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, url-shortener

I am having a node module published on our private npm repo, this module is used for custom logging and other such utilities but none of them has a db call. Now I've to create a url shortner which will use mongodb. I am aware that node has native mongo driver and I am ready to use it my concern is that is it a good idea to have this in my node module? Also, in future I might extend url shortner to keep track of how many times an url has been accessed. So considering these 2 facts I would like to know if this is a good idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "a good idea"? You gotta do what you got to do. Or do you ask whether it should be kept in a separate repo? This purely opinion based question then.

Comment: By good idea I mean that, url_shortner will be consisting of dbcalls unlike other utilities such as logging, generating response and all that, these are developed completely and there is very minor chance that any upgrade would be needed. While url shortner would consist of db calls and might extend in future which will lead to more code. So is it fine for a utility module to have lots of code and db calls?

Comment: Again: purely opinion based. If you ask me, then why not? There's nothing special about db calls. Although it might be wise to use [the dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) for the mongo driver.

Comment: Okay see as it is a utility module most of my microservices will use this. That means all this code is also put in my node_modules folder, but meanwhile I won't be needing a URL shortener everytime so even if it's not being used the code stays in microservices as a deadone. But if I keep it in a separate module I can have install it only when I need it.

Comment: There's always a tradeoff. On one hand you are right: you don't need a code you don't use (on the other hand freeing these few kb of code is not a big deal, right?). On the other hand you end up with lots of libraries and maintaining them becomes an issue. My advice: keep the code in one place for as long as it is easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks that's clears up things for me, I would go with a separate library so if I am to add analytics for links being accessed I can extend it without touching regular and stable utility of mine. But lots of thanks for helping with this :)